# A question on matrix's eigenvalue problem from Eberhard Zeidler's first volume of Nonlinear Functional Analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question from Eberhard Zeidler's book on Non-Linear Functional Analysis, question 1.5a, he gives as a reference for this question the book by Wilkinson called "The Algebraic Eigenvalue Problem", but he doesn't give a page where it appears and it's hard to find exactly the wording suitable for this question.

Anyway, the question is as follows:
Let $A$ be an $N\times N$ matrix with $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors $x_1,\ldots , x_N$ and corrseponding eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, where $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2| \ge |\lambda_3| \ge \ldots \ge |\lambda_N|$.
Let $x^{(0)}=\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i x_i , \ \alpha_1 \ne 0$, and $x^{(n)}=A^nx^{(0)}/\| A^n x^{(0)}\|_{\infty}$. Show that: 
as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $x^{(n)}\rightarrow \frac{x_1}{\|x_1\|_{\infty}}$ and $\|Ax^{(n)}\|_{\infty} \rightarrow \lambda_1$ .

It appears on page 40.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily see that

$$A^nx^{(0)} = \sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i \lambda_i^n x_i$$

You can rewrite that as

$$\lambda_1^n\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^nx_i$$

and then study what happens to $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}$ if $i=1$ or of $i\neq 1$.

Comment: But how do I compute the supremum norm of $A^n x^{(0)}$?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist write the components of $A^nx^{(0)}$, and think about the factor $\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I get that $\|A^nx^{(0)}\|_{\infty} = |\lambda_1|^n$, so $x^{(n)}\rightarrow \alpha_ 1x_1$, but how do I get that $\alpha_1 = 1/\|x_1|_\infty$?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist The equality $||A^n x^{(0)}||_\infty = |\lambda_1|^n$ is wrong. How do I know that? Well, if it was true, then that would be a trivial way of exactly finding $\lambda_1$, and for large matrices, we know that there is no exact (non-iterative) formula for $\lambda_1$

Comment: So, how do I calculate the supremum norm of $A^nx^{(0)}$? I mean by definition it should be: $\| A^n x^{(0)} \|_{\infty} = \sup \| \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \lambda_i^n x_i\|$, and I can't remember how to calculate, I don't remember also on which set do we take the supremum?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Now I finally know what is confusing you! $A^nx^{(0)}$ is a **vector**, not a matrix. Thus, the $||.||_\infty$ norm of it is defined as the maximum absolute value of its components! There is no supremum. There is a maximum over a finite set (of size $N$).

Comment: How do I know what are the components of this vector, I mean as you simply written: $A^n x^{(0)} = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \lambda_i^n x_i$? is this componentwise with regards to eigenvectors, $x_i$? i.e $\| A^n x^{(0)} \|_{\infty} = \max_{1\le j\le N} |\alpha_j| |\lambda_j^n|$?

Comment: You say: "How do I know what are the components of this vector". That is precisely what you need to find out. Let's take a simple example first: If $x_1=[1,2]^T$ and $x_2=[-1,1]^T$ what are the components of the vector $x_1 + x_2$?

Comment: Ok, I understand you, so it should be if $x_i = (x_{i1},\ldots, x_{iN})$, then: $\| A^n x^{(0)} \|_{\infty} = \max\{ |\alpha_1\lambda_1^n x_{11}+\ldots+\alpha_N\lambda_N^nx_{1N}|,\ldots , |\alpha_1\lambda_1^nx_{1N}+\ldots +\alpha_N \lambda_N^n x_{NN}|\}$, how to proceed from here?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Don't forget my trick with putting $\lambda^n$ at the front of each expression. And again, as I said two times before, think about $\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^n$ for $i\neq 1$.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's less than $1$ in absolute value, but I don't see how does it help. I mean we have $\max_{1\le j \le N} |\lambda_1|^n |\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i (\lambda_i/\lambda_1)^n x_{ji}|$. I mean we have: $|\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i (\lambda_i/\lambda_1)^nx_{ji}| \le \sum_{i=1}^N |\alpha_i| |x_{ji}|$, how to continue?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist If $q$ is less than $1$ in absolute value, what happens to $q^n$ as $n$ becomes very large?

Comment: It approaches zero. But really how does this help me to compute this norm? I mean I am clueless as to how use this.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist The full proof is too long. I will not write it down for you. I gave you the basic idea. I advise you to look at the problem a little, the proof is not complicated, but you are still missing several steps. I advise you to take a break.

Comment: Do you happen to know a reference where this is proved, that will help too. I thought from what you wrote that the proof is short. :-)

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist The idea of the proof is very simple. The proof itself is longer. I don't have a reference, sadly.